# Vaadin offline mode and end to end encryption

Tags: java, html, web, vaadin, vaadin7

I am trying to learn Vaadin framework and have been going through the resources on Vaadin website.

I have two questions which so far I have not been able to find a precise answer to.

Since all your business logic is sitting on the server the questions are, can Vaadin do the following with the additional constraint of not using any additional frameworks as much as possible.

1. Can Vaadin be used to create applications that offer limited offline capabilities when there is no internet access, (limited to 'view only' mode) without the use of Touchkit.
2. Can Vaadin be used to create applications that implement end to end encryption (any data the user enters is encrypted client side before being sent to server)

Comment: For 1 yes, but it's not easy at the moment. For 2 you use https

Answer (score 0):

*Can Vaadin be used to create applications that offer limited offline capabilities when there is no internet access, (limited to 'view only' mode) without the use of Touchkit.*

Vaadin might be used to create applicaion with limited offline capabilities because it uses HTML5 "cache manifest" that makes it possible. However, as you are asking to without the usage of "Touchkit"; I guess this might not be possible at the moment.

*Can Vaadin be used to create applications that implement end to end encryption (any data the user enters is encrypted client side before being sent to server)*

I think it might be possible to encrypt client side code before being sent to the server.  In an application where users have read access to data and some users have write access, the domain model can be designed to basically in any way possible. However, if there are groups of users that should be given read access to only some parts of the data, things might be complicated.

Although my answers might not be very convincing, I hope you get some idea out of this.